# How do I close a file if i didn't initialize it?

Tags: python, file, io

If i've done the following:

```
import codecs
lines = codecs.open(somefile, 'r','utf8').readlines()
```

**Is there a way to close the file that i've not initialized? If so, how?** Normally, i could have done:

```
import codecs
reader = codecs.open(somefile, 'r','utf8') 
lines = reader.readlines()
reader.close()
```

Comment: "Initialized" is a strange word here. Is there a way to close a file that you do not have a variable for? No. But as Martijn points out, it tends to get closed by itself, at least when the program exits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CPython, the file object will close on its own once the reference count drops to 0, which is right after `.readlines()` returns. For other Python implementations it may take a little longer depending on the garbage collection algorithm used. The file is certainly going to be closed no later than program exit.

You should really use the file object as a context manager and have the `with` statement call close on it:

```
with codecs.open(somefile, 'r','utf8') as reader:
    lines = reader.readlines()
```

As soon as the block of code indented under the `with` statement exits (be it with an exception, a `return`, `continue` or `break` statement, or simply because all code in the block finished executing), the `reader` file object will be closed.

Bonus tip: file objects are iterables, so the following also works:

```
with codecs.open(somefile, 'r','utf8') as reader:
    lines = list(reader)
```

for the exact same result.

Comment: @2er0: CPython is the default implementation of Python you download from python.org. It is so called because the interpreter itself is implemented in C, as opposed to Jython (in Java), IronPython (in C#) and PyPy (in a subset of Python).